# Remove '\n\n\n', '\n' from python list

Tags: python

How can I remove `'\n\n\n'`, `'\n'`, `u'\xa0'` from the array below?

```
list = ['\n\n\n', '\n', '1', '2', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', u'\xa0', '\n', u'\xa0\xa0', '\n', '3']
```

I have tried `.remove("'\n'")` but I get the error message: list.remove(x): x not in list

Comment: How did they get there in the first place? That might be a better place to solve this.

Comment: `"'\n'"` should just be `"\n"`. The quotes aren't in the string, they're just part of the syntax for creating string literals.

Comment: You don't have any single quotes in the list, use     list.remove("\n"), not     list.remove(" '\n' ")

Answer (score 1):

Use an array comprehension:

`[x for x in list if not x.isspace() and u'\xa0' not in x]`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of targeting the non-alphanumeric characters, search for the alphanumeric characters themselves:

```
import re
l = ['\n\n\n', '\n', '1', '2', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', u'\xa0', '\n', u'\xa0\xa0', '\n', '3']
new_l = filter(lambda x:re.findall('^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$', x), l)
```

Output:

```
['1', '2', '3']
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldnt name the list `list` better something like:

```
 l = ['\n\n\n', '\n', '1', '2', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', u'\xa0', '\n', u'\xa0\xa0', '\n', '3']
```

Then you can try `filter`:

```
 > list(filter(lambda x: '\n' not in x and u'\xa0' not in x, l))
 > ['1', '2', '3']
```